# Stop vim-latex from autocompiling on save

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I'm not sure if it has always happened or its just recent, but vim auto-compiles on each save (`:w`). I would like to only manually compile (I use a hot-keyed pdflatex command instead).

I've had a quick google and read through the manual and nothing has jumped out at me. Anyone know how to do this?

Update: Relevant lines in vimrc

```
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on
" `Ctrl` + `P` compiles latest save of current .tex file to pdf
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <c-p> <ESC>:!pdflatex %<CR>
```

NB: Plug-in manager is [junegunn/vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)

Update 2: Turns out I did it back when I first got latex.. Really should be keeping a record of changes I make

Comment: Are you sure this is vim-latex? Can you provide a link to the plugin that you are using?

Comment: @Karl [vim-latex/vim-latex](http://www.github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) edit: ... I'm a goober and can't read instructions/remember how to SE

Comment: I cannot confirm that vim-latex has the functionality of automatically compiling on `:w`. Could you try a minimal installation as described here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/vim-latex-installation-confusion/17946#17946?

Comment: I have a suggestion for your mapping: Use `autocmd FileType tex nmap <c-p> <Plug>Tex_Compile` instead of yours. The quickfix list is then automatically filled with LaTeX errors which makes it easier to navigate to them. For example, try it with a `Hello World` file and add deliberately an error by inserting `_` outside of a math environment. After compilation your cursor should immediately be placed on the line with the `_`.

Comment: I should add following to my previous comment: to generate a pdf immediately on windows or linux, add following to your vimrc: `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'`.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was wrong, so I did some digging through the plugin file system, and found a file that had been edited 3 days after downloading the plugin (last mod date was the key). At the bottom of one of the files I found the culprit! `au BufWritePost *.tex silent call Tex_RunLaTeX()` from [Vim tips wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Compiling_LaTeX_from_Vim#Vim-Latex_plugin)

Answer (score 1):

### Debugging Autocmds

If something happens automatically for a certain command (here `:write`) in vim, an autocmd might be the reason for this.

If you already know the event of the autocmd, you can see the autocmds with

```
:autocmd <Event Name>
```

as described under [`:h autocmd-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-list).

In your case likely candidates are

```
:autocmd BufWritePost
:autocmd BufWrite
:autocmd FileWritePost
:autocmd FileWrite
```

To see also the filenames where these autocmds are defined, run

```
:verbose autocmd <Event Name>
```

A list of events used by the autocmds can be found under

[`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events)

Since this list is quite long and you might have no clue where to start, a second method is to invoke your command prefixed with `:9verbose`. In your case

```
:9verbose write
```

The count `9` is important so that also autocmds are listed. This is described under [`:h 'verbose'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27verbose%27)