# Vim-latex not starting automatically for .tex files

Tags: vimrc, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I have Vim on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to use the [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) package. By typing `:set rtp?` on Vim I get the following output:

> runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/vim-latex-1.10.0,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after

From that, it seems to me that the vim-latex package is indeed installed. However, I haven't been able to make the package start automatically once I open a latex file on vim. I am assuming (maybe incorrectly, so I would thank any corrections to my thinking) that this is happening because I haven't completed [step 2](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) of the vim-latex installation as in their Installation Instructions page, which includes adding `filetype plugin on` to my `~/.vimrc.`

By typing `:version` on Vim, I get the following output:

> system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
> user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
> 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"

Inspecting my system, I couldn't find `$HOME/.vimrc`, so I created one. I could find `~/.vim/vimrc`, but my system did not let me make changes to it. Nevertheless, when I start a .tex file on Vim I believe it still does not start the package as I don't see anything similar to what is describe in this [tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-inserting-template.html).

Some further details:
By running `:filetype` I get `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`. I was getting `indent:OFF` before adding the line for indetation in my `$HOME/.vimrc`, so I believe it is getting the right file.

By running `:verbose set ft?` I get:

> filetype=plaintex
> Defined last time in /usr/share/vim/vim80/autoload/dist/ft.vim

By running `scriptnames` I get:

> 1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
> 2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
> 3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
> 4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
> 5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
> 7: ~/.vimrc
> 8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
> 9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
> 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
> 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
> 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
> 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
> 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
> 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
> 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
> 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
> 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
> 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
> 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
> 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
> **22: ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/vim-latex-1.10.0/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim**
> **23: ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/vim-latex-1.10.0/plugin/filebrowser.vim**
> **24: ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/vim-latex-1.10.0/plugin/imaps.vim**
> **25: ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/vim-latex-1.10.0/plugin/remoteOpen.vim**
> 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/autoload/dist/ft.vim
> 27: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/plaintex.vim
> 28: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/initex.vim
> 29: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/plaintex.vim
> 30: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/initex.vim

I will be very grateful to anyone that can help me figure out what's happening. I would like to apologize in advance if I did not provide all the details needed (I am new to Vim). Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

OBS: Following [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/vim-latex-installation-confusion) I have added the tree path of my vim-latex installation if it helps:

```
~/.vim$ tree -L 5
.  
├── pack  
│   └── bundle  
│       └── start  
│           └── vim-latex-1.10.0  
│               ├── compiler  
│               ├── doc  
│               ├── ftplugin  
│               ├── indent  
│               ├── latextags  
│               ├── ltags  
│               ├── Makefile  
│               ├── Makefile.in  
│               ├── plugin  
│               ├── README.md  
│               └── vim-latex.metainfo.xml  
├── tags  
└── tags-te
```

Comment: When you use the `:filetype` command to check whether it's enabled, do you see `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`? When you open a LaTeX file, what does `:verbose set ft?` tell you? After opening the LaTeX file, use the `:scriptnames` command to see which Vim scripts and plug-ins were loaded. Please [edit] the question to include this information.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden, thanks! I have edited my question as you asked.

Comment: Not being able to edit ~/.vim/vimrc is concerning, though likely irrelevant to the question. I prefer to keep my vimrc there because then all my vim files are in one directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your file is being recognized as `filetype=plaintex`, which means TeX (or '"plain" TeX) and not LaTeX, and the `latex-suite` plug-ins only enable most of their commands on LaTeX files. LaTeX files are identified by `filetype=tex` (which can indeed seem quite confusing.)

Since files with the extension `*.tex` can be TeX or LaTeX (or even the perhaps lesser known [ConTeXt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt)), Vim will try to "guess" which is right for a specific file, usually based on the file's contents.

The code implementing this auto-detection can be found in [`dist#ft#FTtex`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/autoload/dist/ft.vim#L644,L648) and it will detect a `*.tex` file as LaTeX if:

- Its first line is a comment of the form `%&LaTeX`.
- It can find one of `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{`, `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand' in the first 1000 lines of the file.
- Otherwise, if the global variable `g:tex_flavor` is set to `'latex'`.

My recommendation is that, if you plan to use LaTeX exclusively or almost exclusively, then setting the `g:tex_flavor` variable in your vimrc is the best approach. That will also help ensure that new `*.tex` files you create will already be recognized as LaTeX files, before they have any content that triggers the auto-detection.

Add the following line to your vimrc:

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

See also [`:help ft-latex-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ft-tex-plugin).

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, now I get `filetype=tex`. I have added `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` to `$VIM/vimrc`. In order to edit it, I ran `sudo vim vimrc` (so not being able to edit it was just a matter of lack of permission for my user). I am now struggling with something else, as I can't find `Tex-Suite > Templates` to insert the templates as explained in the vim-latex tutorial [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-inserting-template.html). However, I guess I should start a new question to solve this instead of editing this one, right?

Comment: Yes, please ask a new question. Please note that `$VIM/vimrc` is the "global" vimrc file and probably not the one you should be changing, since it's likely to be overwritten when Vim is upgraded. What you want is your user vimrc file, which will be `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` (Vim will use the first of these two that it can find.)

Comment: Thanks @filbraden. I have it updated in my `~/.vimrc` too, but for some reason it wasn't working. It only worked when I added it to `$VIM/vimrc`. But that's good information, I will know where to look at in case I have issues with that in the future.

Comment: It's odd, output of `:scriptnames` shows your Vim is definitely sourcing your `~/.vimrc`, and the value of this variable is only evaluated at runtime, only when a `*.tex` file is actually opened... If you have the setting in `~/.vimrc` only, does `:verbose let g:tex_flavor` confirm it's set to `'latex'` (and set from your `~/.vimrc`)?

Comment: @filbraden, now it is working. I deleted let `g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` from `$VIM/vimrc`, but things kept working. Not sure what happened before, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @filbraden, I have posted my other issue mentioned above in a new question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27343/unable-to-select-templates-with-vim-latex). If you by any chance now how to solve it I would be very grateful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer ! I ran into the same issue and this resolved it : )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using a (different) plugin to get that functionality, https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).