# Unable to select templates with vim-latex

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I have Vim on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have sucessfully installed the [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) package. When I open a `.tex` file, vim regognizes it as latex and the plugin kicks in (I have already struggled with this a few days ago as shown [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27272/vim-latex-not-starting-automatically-for-tex-files). If I ran `:verbose set ft?` I get `filetype=tex`as my output). However, if I understand the official [tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-inserting-template.html) of this package, once I start a new file I should have some way  of selecting a new template in `Tex-Suite > Templates`. Unfortunately, I believe I do not currently have this option on my Vim as show in the picture below (notice that my system is in Portuguese, so I have added another picture with the translation of the options I have on Vim just below):

[image: The options available in my Vim]

[image: Options in English]

I have searched in the above menus, but I haven't found any options to add templates. So I don't really have any new options when working on a `.tex` file. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something to get my `vim-latex`working properly? Please, let me know if I can add any other useful information here so I can edit my question properly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Vim menus are only enabled in the GUI version of Vim. So if you use GVim on Linux you should see the menus and the menus added by plug-ins such as those from vim-latex will be available too.

You can enable menus on the terminal, but you need to do so explicitly. See [`:help console-menus`](https://vimhelp.org/gui.txt.html#console-menus):

> Although this documentation is in the GUI section, you can actually use menus in console mode too. You will have to load `menu.vim` explicitly then, it is not done by default. You can use the `:emenu` command and command-line completion with `'wildmenu'` to access the menu entries almost like a real menu system. To do this, put these commands in your `.vimrc` file:
>
> ```
> source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
> set wildmenu
> set cpo-=<
> set wcm=<C-Z>
> map <F4> :emenu <C-Z>
> ```
>
> Pressing `<F4>` will start the menu. You can now use the cursor keys to select a menu entry. Hit `<Enter>` to execute it. Hit `<Esc>` if you want to cancel. This does require the `+menu` feature enabled at compile time.

These "menus" also behave somewhat differently from what you typically think of menus in a graphical application. The options are always shown horizontally, just above the command-line, and once you enter a menu, the submenu is also displayed horizontally on that same line. It might be a little awkward to use and get used to...

Overall, menus can be helpful as you're learning to use a plug-in, but since they actually always map to a Vim command, using the commands directly might end up being quicker and easier in the long term.

---

In the specific case of vim-latex's `Tex-Suite > Templates`, the corresponding command is `:TTemplate`, which takes a template name as its argument. It has tab completion enabled, so you can use `:TTemplate <Tab>` to go through the list of available templates, which gives you every piece of information and all features you would get from that specific menu.

Comment: again, thanks a lot for your help! It is working perfectly now!